# Password change effective against signing in from another PS4 console?

Tags: ps4, psn

I was recently being logged out of my PS4 (PS+ account) automatically when someone else somehow signed in to his PS4 using my ID. I have changed my password as soon as I saw that. But I would like to ask would this be enough to stop him from signing in again using my ID? I am not sure whether he will sign out from my account or not, only then I think the new password will be effective against him? If he doesn't sign out then how can I protect my account from him to have signed in again in future?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to figure out a complicated password, just set up [2-step verification](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/playstation-network/two-step-verification/) for your account:

> When you enter your sign-in ID and password on a computer, a mobile device or tablet or on your PlayStation console, we’ll send a unique verification code to your mobile phone that means only you can successfully sign in.

You just need an authenticator app like [Google Authenticator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2).